# How can i build my Xamarin iOS Solution with iPad Simulator configuration?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I am building an iOS App in Xamarin Studio on MAC.

When i build my application, i get an error of "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you app target iPad, just select iPhone/Simulator and iPad should show up in the list of simulators. Also check your XCode + SDK installation.

Comment: This didn't worked when I already removed iPhone Simulator from the General Tab inside configuration.